# Mapping c# string with entity framework to sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm committing a dotnetcore identity model to my sqlite database but it's having trouble mapping a text field to the sqlite `text` data type for some reason.

This is out of the box - nothing special about this at all:

```
public partial class CreateIdentitySchema : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            });
```

The columns for `Id`, `Name,`, and `NormalizedName` all appear to have no issues, but `ConcurrencyStamp` gives the problem:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" nvarchar(450) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" nvarchar(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" nvarchar(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" nvarchar(max) NULL
);
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'near "max": syntax error'.
```

Note that I am using the most recent version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.3" />
```

And my configuration builds it on sqlite as well:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
```

What's the resolution? Clearly the migration has built the model incorrectly but what do I change?

Comment: seems like sqlite doesnt like `max` in `nvarchar(max)` (I've tested in db browser for sqlite - and still it doesn like) .. just give `ConcurrencyStamp` some size like you did in other columns ... It may be also a bug in `MigrationBuilder` since it should generate code which given database understand

Comment: by the way ... you can go with 255 or any other as SQlite don't give a s... about this parameter there are only 5 types of data in sqlite `NULL`, `INTEGER`, `REAL`, `TEXT`, `BLOB` ... so there is no variable char size ... `[N][VAR]CHAR(X)` is treated as `TEXT`